# High weights at shoulder barbell press

Tags: weightlifting, shoulders

I was attentioned at the gym today by a "gym bro" that doing shoulder presses with the barbell at a total of 50kg barbell + weigths is dangerous and nobody should do it. I am doing 5x5 reps and i find the 50 kg weigth comfortable. Should i worry about something ? Is it too exagerated to do shoulder press with 50 kg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The barbell overhead press used to be one of the lifts contested in Olympic Weightlifting, and [competitors pressed more than 200kg overhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_Olympic_weightlifting#Men_(1920%E2%80%931972)) without any incidence of injury. (The press was later removed from Olympic Weightlifting only because it was deemed too difficult to judge. And maybe because the Soviets were too good at it.)

I would advise you to just dismiss the Gym Bro by saying, "Yeah, thanks. I'll keep that in mind", and then go right back to pressing.

Comment: 100% agree to that. Given that you're doing the movement correct and you're comfortable with the weight, there shouldn't be much to worry about.

Comment: Thank you, I really feel alot better and confident now.

Comment: As long as you’re not pressing behind your head...

Comment: @Frank I would never destroy my rotator with that dumb exercise...:D

Comment: The thing is, I was also amazed to hear hes a "professional" fighter and did powerlifting for like 6-7 years and bodybuilding for the same amount, but he never lifted so much weight (50 kg) over his head